# Redis using lots of RAM, steadily increasing until I restart it

Tags: memory, keys, redis

I have a simple redis installation and it seems to slowly eat more and more ram at a steady incline until I restart the redis server.

I'm using redis as a caching layer, currently I don't set an expire on my keys as I didn't think that was necessary. I thought redis would drop off old keys or something - though clearly this isn't happening.

Whats the best way of handling this kind of situation, should I set a short expire time on my keys or is there some functionality built into redis to expire old keys to make room for new ones?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Redis isn't memcached, you know.

Answer (score 1):

Redis's old tag line is: "A persistent key-value database with built-in net interface written in ANSI-C for Posix systems".

I believe keys are persistent by default.  You'll have to set EXPIRE on keys that you actually want to go away after a while.  As womble noted, it ain't memcached.

For the command reference: http://redis.io/topics/expire

Comment: Thanks for your comments :) I think i'll move to something like memcached instead as although redis works great... it wasn't really built for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `maxmemory` configuration variable in your redis conf and then set the `maxmemory-policy` to either `allkeys-lru` or `allkeys->random` which will allow keys to be removed from the database and make redis act like a cache. Since you're using it as a cache you can comment out all `save` lines so redis won't save to disk.

This is probably the easiest way and you won't have to switch to memcached, I suggest the `allkeys-lru` which will allow any key to be removed with the ones that are least recently used being removed first.